# supressing Eclipse error messages

Tags: eclipse, ux

I'm frequently getting seemingly random NullPointer exceptions thrown that are shown to me in alert windows that steal my focus and force me to click the 'ok' button then everything is working fine.. So I'd like to know how I can have these error messages silent, so that they don't kill my productivity.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be "Why is eclipse throwing nullPointerExceptions"?

Comment: Everything only looks working fine I think...

Comment: well everything I care about is working fine, something that I don't care about is not.  I think it is the spell checking, code completion, or some equally useless feature, it seems to happen when my wpm spike.